# How do I move a list to another board in Trello?

Tags: trello

I can easily drag cards between lists, and I can also rearrange the lists in a board but I am not seeing a way to move a list to another board?

Is this possible?

Comment: It's been implemented, see https://trello.com/card/move-cards-between-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/968

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the link.  I'm still not able to decipher exactly how to do this...  I've [opened another question here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39021/32949) -- hopefully you can enlighten?

Comment: Ok, found it -- [the answer and a screenshot is here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39022/32949).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Moving a list to another board is not currently possible, but it's an [idea that's under consideration](https://trello.com/card/board/move-a-list-to-another-board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4ec56ea287dd14043d149b72)

Comment: +1 You really deserve +2 (1 for answering my question and 1 for showing me where to view and make other suggestions) :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this manually?

Comment: @ripper234 Yes, there is a way. First create a new board. Then for each card in the list you want to move, click its dropdown, select "Move" and select the new board (and potentially a list).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like they implemented this a couple months ago.  Hover over your list, click the chevron next to the title, and choose "Move List".

Comment: Strange that Move List can go to another board but Copy List can't.

Comment: Also strange that "Move all cards in this list" doesn't allow selecting another board, but "Move list" does??? Very weird.

Answer (score 3):

First copy the list in the same board and after move the list to another board

Comment: How do you suggest copying the list? Can you provide more clear steps for users?

Answer (score 2):

Moving a list to another board is definitely feasible.

You can follow the steps illustrated from the official help:
http://help.trello.com/article/806-moving-cards-or-lists

Where it tells you that:

"You can also move lists to other boards from the list's menu. Click on the current board to select the new target board."

Notice that you have to click on the current board like the picture shows below:

[image]

Then it will open a pull-down menu and you can find what ever board you have created and choose any of them to move into.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did as a work around:

I opened boards in different browser tabs and copy and pasted the information in the from one board to another. It works nicely.