# How do I move a list to another board in Trello (now it's been implemented)?

Tags: trello, trello-boards, trello-lists

I see from [a previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18962/32949) that this feature has now been implemented.

But although [the provided link](http://help.trello.com/article/806-moving-cards-or-lists) takes me to the Feature card in Trello development, I can't decipher (in plain English), what I'm supposed to do to get my list to move from one board to another.

Is anyone able to shed light on this?

Comment: @pnuts- fixed the broken link to Trello help topic - tx.

Answer (score 4):

Right, found it.

Hover the cursor above a list (assuming you're using a desktop -- it'll be slightly different for an Android or iPad).

You'll see a down button appear.  Clicking it brings up a list of options, of which `Move List...` is one of them.

The screenshot below shows how:

[image]

Comment: Note: after selecting "Move List" it may only show your current board, clicking the current board in that list will bring up a list of other boards.  This is non-obivious IMHO.